# Number of pairs $(i, j)$ where $1\leq i < j \leq N$ such that $i|j$

Tags: number-theory, summation

This is a programming question so I tried like this:

```
for (int i=1; N/i != 1; i++)
    sum += N/i-1;
```

I am getting the correct answer. But one solution I saw by somebody which I could not understand which is :

```
for (int i=1; i<=sqrt(N); i++) 
    sum += N/i;

ans = 2*sum - sqrt(N)*sqrt(N) - N
```

How this formula can be derived, I am not able to get that. Please help me in this regard.

**To explain it in more clear way :**

The number of integers in $\{1, ..., N\}$ that are divisible by $i$ (excluding $i$ itself) equals $N/i - 1$.

For example, $N = 5$, there are $5/1$ (i.e. $5$) numbers $(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)$ which are divisible by $1$ and there are $5/2$ (i.e. $2$) numbers $(2, 4)$ which are divisible by $2$

For calculating the total number of pairs, I am adding all the values $(N/i - 1)$ where $i\ge 1$ and $N/i > 1$.

for example,

```
For N=5, 
    sum = (5/1 - 1) + (5/2 - 1) = 4 + 1 = 5

for N = 6,
    sum = (6/1 - 1) + (6/2 - 1) + (6/3 - 1) = 5 + 2 + 1 = 8
```

This is giving correct answer. But I saw one solution which is like this :

First it is adding all the values $N/i$ where $1\le i\le \text{sqrt}(N)$.

for example,

```
For N=6, 
    sum = 6/1 + 6/2 = 6 + 3 = 9
```

Then it is calculating the answer as:

```
ans = 2*sum - sqrt(N)*sqrt(N) - N    (*)

    = 2*9 - 2*2 - 6 = 8
```

**NB**: In all of the above, the $/$ mark denotes *integer division*, i.e. $N/i := \left \lfloor \frac{N}{i}\right\rfloor$, and $\text{sqrt}$ denotes *integer square root*, i.e. $\text{sqrt}(N) = \left \lfloor \sqrt{N} \right\rfloor$.

Can anyone help me how to derive the formula (*)?

**EDIT**: The mathematical question may be stated as asking how to establish the following identity in the positive integer variable $N$:

$$\sum_{i\ = \ 1..\ \left \lfloor \frac{N}{2}\right\rfloor} \left(\left \lfloor \frac{N}{i}\right\rfloor - 1\right )\ \ =\ \ 2\left( \sum_{i\ =\ 1..\ \left\lfloor\sqrt N \right\rfloor} \left \lfloor \frac{N}{i}\right\rfloor \right)- {\left\lfloor\sqrt N \right\rfloor}^2 - N
$$

Comment: StackOverflow?.

Comment: Would you kindly write the algorithm instead of the code? I suspect many people here would not be able to understand what the code means. But I assure you that they can help you with the other expression *if they understand your question*.

Answer (score 1):

The number of pairs you look at can be written in  more convinient way as: 
   $$ \sum_{i=1}^N \left\lfloor \frac{N}{i} \right \rfloor - N $$
The sum in the left can be seen as the number of points with integral coordinates under the the hyperbola $xy=N$, the colored region in the figure (including the borders).

Now call $A, B, C$ the sets of points with integral coordinates in each of the regions shown in the figure, where the points with integral coordinates lying in $B$ are counted only in $B$. Then by symmetry $\lvert A \rvert = \lvert C \rvert $ and thus the total number of points is given under the hyperbola is given by 
 $$ \lvert A \rvert+\lvert B \rvert+\lvert C \rvert=2(\lvert A \rvert + \lvert B \rvert)- \lvert B \rvert $$
$\lvert A \rvert+\lvert B \rvert$ is given by the sum
$$ \sum_{i\le \sqrt{N}} \left\lfloor \frac{N}{i} \right \rfloor $$
and the number of points in $B$ is clearly 
$$\lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor^2$$

So finally the number of pairs is

$$ \sum_{i=1}^N \left\lfloor \frac{N}{i} \right \rfloor - N = 2(\lvert A \rvert + \lvert B \rvert)- \lvert B \rvert-N = 2\sum_{i\le \sqrt{N}} \left\lfloor \frac{N}{i} \right \rfloor  -\lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor^2 -N $$
[image]

Comment: There are some typos: the -|A| should be -|B|, and there is a $2$ in the last line. It might be clearer to write  
$$\sum_{i=1}^N \left\lfloor \frac{N}{i} \right \rfloor - N = |A|+|B|+|C|-N = 2(|A|+|B|)-|B| - N = 2\sum_{i\le \sqrt{N}} \left\lfloor \frac{N}{i} \right \rfloor - \lfloor \sqrt{N} \rfloor^2 - N
$$

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've edited the answer with your sugestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. I was struggling to get this.